# Trying to test when user inputs code if the code is already sorted

Tags: java, sorting

I keep trying different kinds of code and I always come back to this. but it never seems to work. The last if statement is making the i's underlined red but I can't even understand why. The homework was to make a program that takes user input and put it into an array and see if the user input is already sorted. Please Help!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Sorting
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the array size: ");
    int a = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the numbers using spaces between each number: ");
    int[] numbers = new int[a];
    for (int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++)
    {
        numbers[i]=input.nextInt();
        if(isSorted(numbers))
        {
            System.out.println("Sort is already sorted");
        }
        else
        {
             System.out.println("Sort is not sorted sorry");
        }
    }
}
public static boolean isSorted(int[] numbers)
{
 for(int i = 0; i<numbers.length-1; i++);
 {
     if(numbers[i]>numbers[i+1])
     {
         return false;
     }
 }
 return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Close the for loop before the if statement.

Comment: the if statement needs to be included in the for loop

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i<numbers.length-1; i++); //<===== remove the ';' here
```

I think you missed place the `;` after the for loop and that cause your issue.